# Geometric problem about $\frac{[DEF]}{[ABC]}$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> $\triangle ABC$ is inscribed in $\odot O$ with radius $R$. The foot of $P$ to $AB$, $BC$, $CA$ are $F$, $D$, $E$ respectively. Show that
> \[\dfrac{[DEF]}{[ABC]}=\dfrac{R^2-OP^2}{4R^2}.\]
>
> [image]

I use barycentric coordinates. Let $P~(n,p,m)$. So $[PBC]=n$ then $PD=\frac{2n}a$. Similarly, $PE=\frac{2p}b$. So
\[\frac{[PDE]}{[ABC]}=\frac{PD\cdot PE\cdot\sin\angle EPD}{CA\cdot CB\cdot\sin\angle ACB}=\frac{4np}{a^2b^2}.\]
Similarly we can find the other two ratios. Notice $R=\frac{abc}{4[ABC]}=\frac{abc}4$ then
\[\dfrac{[DEF]}{[ABC]}=\dfrac{4mpa^2+4mnb^2+4npc^2}{a^2b^2c^2}=\frac{mpa^2+mnb^2+npc^2}{4R^2}.\]
We have already the denominator but how to prove the numerator? I know that bary has got distance formula, but I cannot compute it out? There's trigonometry that I cannot eliminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. Use Power of a Point.

> Consider this useful result: Let $\Omega$ be a circle given by the following equation: $$\Omega : −a^2yz − b^2zx − c^2xy + (ux + vy + wz)(x + y + z) = 0$$ for some constants $u,v,w$. Furthermore, let $P = (x_p, y_p, z_p)$ be a point with normalized barycentric coordinates. Then, the power $\mathbb{P}(P, \Omega)$ of the point $P$ with respect to the circle $\Omega$ is $$\mathbb{P}(P, \Omega)= −a^2y_pz_p −b^2z_px_p −c^2x_py_p +(ux_p +vy_p +wz_p)$$ For a point $P = (x_p : y_p : z_p)$ with homogeneous coordinates, it's just $$\mathbb{P}(P, \Omega)= \frac1{(x_p+y_p+z_p)^2}\cdot \left(−a^2y_pz_p −b^2z_px_p −c^2x_py_p +(ux_p +vy_p +wz_p)(x_p+y_p+z_p)\right)$$

> As for the proof, it boils down to annoying calculations (combine the proof for the equation of a circle and the distance formula).

> Now, in your problem, $OP^2-R^2$ is just the power $\mathbb{P}(P, \odot O)$ of $P$ with respect to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ and $u=v=w=0$.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about this formula. I'll keep trying to solve the problem. By thw way, I've just checked, this is $\sf lemma$ $7.23$ on EGMO.

Comment: But this solves the problem, doesn't it? (see the third hint :))

Comment: Yes and I've done it. I only looked at the first one at that time.

Comment: I see, I'm glad it helped :D